# Modifying Typescript files in the Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible in the Chrome dev tools when I hit a breakpoint and end up in a .ts file due to the source mapping, to make local modifications and save the changes to the .ts file on disk? I'm not having any luck it keeps saying my changes cannot be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried with TypeScript but when the source file loads as a result of the source map, if the file is in your workspace it should be persisted when you save changes.

See [Setting up Persistence with DevTools Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en)

Comment: Yes it does work fine, I had it configured improperly.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/